# Finding the length of all substrings in string

Tags: c++, substring

I have a function that I am writing called word_length(). The purpose of it is to take a string, read it out and give the length of each word in the string from a particular starting position. The code so far will give me the length from the start of the entire string to the beginning of the word I input. I imagine a for loop to run it through the whole string but not sure if this is going in the right direction so far.

```
std::string str ("This is the test string I am going to use.");
std::cout << "The size of " << str << " is " << str.length() << " characters.\n";

int start_pos;
int next_pos;
int word_length = 0;

string word = "";

//for (unsigned i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
//{
unsigned pos = str.find("the");
cout << "The size of the word " << word <<  " is " << pos << endl;
//}
```

Comment: If the string's length is `x` then the lengths of all the substrings of `x` is `[0,1,...,x]`

Comment: Should `unsigned pos = str.find("the");` be called like `unsigned pos = str.find(word);`?

Answer (score 0):

If your words are space-seperated, then it is sufficient to search for spaces.

```
void print_lens(const string & s)
{
    int old = 0, now = 1;
    while (now < s.size())
    {
        if (!isspace(s[now])) { ++now; continue; }
        string word = s.substr(old, now - old);
        cout << "A word: " << word << ", its length is " << word.size() << endl;
        old = now + 1;
    }
    string word = s.substr(old, s.size() - old);
    cout << "A word: " << word << ", its length is " << word.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Now I have it to find the length of the first word, but then it takes the length of the rest of the remaining string, instead of the next word, and the next. Would a strtok() be sufficient in doing that?